# To apply L'Hôpital's Rule?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

If we have the following functions which are differential  and continuous.

$\int_0^\infty F(t,a)dt$ $\,\,\,$  and$\,\,\,\,\,$  $\int_0^\infty G(t,a)dt$

And Let us suppose that our these  functions satisfy the general conditions to apply L'Hôpital's Rule.

$\lim_{u\to \infty}\int_0^u F(t,a_o)dt=0$ $\,\,\,$  and$\,\,\,\,\,$  $\lim_{u\to \infty}\int_0^u G(t,a_o)dt=0$

...

**THE QUESTION**: I have presented the following three items about "L'Hôpital's Rules". Which one is correct?

**i-)** Can we apply  L'Hôpital's Rule with respect to the parameter $´u´$ to the following-equation **directly as without considerening anything else**.

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{ \int_0^u F(t,a_o) \, dt}{\int_0^u G(t,a_o) \, dt} $$

**ii-)**   **Or before** to apply L'Hôpital's Rule with respect to the parameter $u$ to the above-equation, do we need to also **to prove** the following one?

There exists a number $c$ as $c> 0$.

The denominator $\,\,$  $\int_0^u G(t,a_o)dt$ $\,\,$ should **not** equal to zero for any$\,\,\,\,$ $u > c$.

For example, if we have the following possibility,  can we apply L'Hôpital's Rule?

$$\lim_{u\to 500}\int_0^u G(t,a_o)dt=0$$

**iii-)** Or we have to look **only** at the  **"neighborhood of infinity"**

I mean  if  there is a possibility for a sufficiently large $u$ value that the denominator can  equal zero, for example:

$$\lim_{u\to 10^{100000}}\int_0^u G(t,a_o)dt=0$$

Can we apply L'Hôpital's Rule?

**Note:** Please note I am **not asking** anything about $\,\,$ $ \frac{d}{du} {\int_0^u G(t,a_o) \, dt}$

Comment: Dear Friends ,  any your valuable comments ?